# Don't know what to do next $\int_{\frac{a+1}{a}}^{a+1} \frac{\ln(x-1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{x-1}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the next integral:$$\int_{\frac{a+1}{a}}^{a+1} \frac{\ln(x-1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{x-1}}\, dx,\ \ a>0 $$

I tried to it with the substitution $t=\sqrt{x-1}$ and now I have:
$$4\int_{\sqrt\frac{1}{a}}^\sqrt{a} \frac{\ln t}{t(t^2+1)}\, dt $$
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: wouldnt it simplify into 4 ln(x)/(x²+1) dx

Comment: That's true....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral simplifies to
$$
I=4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\ln t}{t^2+1}\, dt
$$ and by making substitution $s=1/t$, we get
$$
I=4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\ln t}{t^2+1}\, dt=4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{-\ln s}{s^2+1}\, ds=-I
$$ hence $I=0$.

Comment: How does one t simplifies?

Comment: I don't think if that is corrext because of dt and ds

Comment: @Gaboru By letting $t=\sqrt{x-1}$, $dt = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$, we have $\frac1{x}\ln(x-1)=2\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2}$ and thus$$\int \ln(x-1)^{1/x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-1}}=4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} dt.$$ Now, substitution $s=1/t$ gives $dt=-1/s^2 ds$ and hence$$4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} dt=4\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{1/\sqrt{a}} \frac{-\ln(s)}{1+s^{-2}} \frac{ds}{-s^2}=4\int_{1/\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{-\ln(s)}{s^2+1} ds.$$

Comment: Thank you very much